# Passing Values to UIViewController in new Storyboard - Swift

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, swift

I am trying to pass values to a new view controller - located within a new storyboard file. However when I do so, the result I get from the NewViewController is always nil.

Below is how I show the view controller within the new storyboard:

```
// Show create account page with custom transition
var storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryboardName, bundle: nil)
var vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(NewViewController) as UIViewController
```

I try to send the information here:

```
// Pass the delegate to the first view controller
let newViewController:NewViewController = NewViewController()
newViewController.createAccountDelegate = self
newViewController.teststring = "hello"
```

And then present the view controller.

```
vc.transitioningDelegate = self
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is my NewViewController, where I try to receive the values. However end up still being nil.

```
import UIKit

class NewViewController: UIViewController {
    var createAccountDelegate:AccountCreationDelegate!
    var teststring:NSString!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

Am I sending the values incorrectly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `NewViewController` with this line

```
let newViewController:NewViewController = NewViewController()
```

Instead assign variables and delegate to `vc` which you have instantiated from `StoryBoard`

```
var storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryboardName, bundle: nil)
// It is instance of  `NewViewController` from storyboard 
var vc : NewViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(NewViewController) as NewViewController

// Pass delegate and variable to vc which is NewViewController
vc.createAccountDelegate = self
vc.teststring = "hello"
vc.transitioningDelegate = self
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: why this is happening though it was working before and now very strange behaviour